# Who came up with the "Hot Dog" theme for flair?

Tags: discussion, flair

Who designed it, and where does he live? >:P

Seriously, what is the purpose of it? For use on geocities?
Does anyone actually use it?

Comment: Erghh. I can't read this question without fixing stackoverflow's ugly layout first. Console to the rescue: `var s=document.createElement("style");document.head.appendChild(s);s.innerHTML=".site-header, .left-sidebar, #content { background-color: red; }\n";s.innerHTML+=".question-page, .container, .question, .answer, .inner-content { background-color: yellow; }\n"`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I believe it's a [tribute](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/07/a-tribute-to-the-windows-31-hot-dog-stand-color-scheme.html) to Windows 3.1's "Hotdog Stand" theme

[image]

Comment: Okay, let's pass the buck then.  Who at Microsoft can we <strike>blame</strike>credit for this theme?

Comment: lol @ "Microsoft Bob" icon.

Comment: AH! MY EYES! THEY BURN!

Comment: Could you cover this with freehand circles?

Comment: Well, there go my retinas.

Comment: [It's... beautiful!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony)

Comment: The Colour Out of Space

Answer (score 16):

It's a color palette trojan horse:

[image]
[(source)](http://www.reallifecomics.com/archive/091011.html)

Comment: No votes; the comic's not xkcd. :)

Comment: Why does everyone seem to hate Comic Sans? It's just a font.

Comment: @CABAG - fixed.

Comment: @Adam: xD [15 chars]

Comment: -1 not related to the question, +1000 Comic Sans hate

Comment: @Adam, you get the +1 just for doing that. :) In fact, you have quite literally made my day with that edit.

Comment: @Adam That's really crude. Why don't you use Comic Sans MS to type XKCD with?

Answer (score 8):

Why hate the hotdog?  It's a beautiful colour scheme.  I really like the subtle balance between the yellows and reds.  It reminds me of walking through an orchard on a warm summers day with a slight floral aroma hanging in the air.  Hand in hand with a lover, gazing into each others eyes, laughing, oh how we laughed as we rolled down a grassy hillock in the meadow!

But seriously, I imagine it's a high contrast scheme designed for the visually impaired maybe?

Comment: Hmmm, what web site would only have visually impaired visitors, to make using that theme suitable for a flair?

Comment: Beautiful... maybe, but subtle no way.

Comment: @Arjan I think the original windows theme might have been for the visually impaired, the SO one is just in memory of that theme maybe!